# Audio to spectrogram image and back to audio

Tags: python, jpeg, librosa, spectrogram

I am able to convert a wav file to spectrogram and then back again with an acceptable level of quality. I can plot and save that spectrogram as jpg file, but I have been able to import the jpg and convert it back to audio.

I can convert the audio to a db scaled spectrogram

```
import librosa
x, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('trumpet'))
X = librosa.stft(x)
Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
```

And I am able to convert the db scaled spectrogram back to audio

```
X2 = librosa.db_to_amplitude(Xdb)
audio = librosa.griffinlim(X2)
import soundfile as sf
sf.write("test1.wav", audio, sr)
```

I can save the array as a 32bit Tiff, and recreate the audio from that tiff file.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im =Image.fromarray(Xdb).convert('F')
im.save("test.tiff")
img = Image.open("test.tiff")
recspec = np.array(img)

X2 = librosa.db_to_amplitude(recspec)
audio = librosa.griffinlim(X2)
import soundfile as sf
sf.write("test1.wav", audio, sr)
```

I can plot the db scaled spectrogram and save it as a jpg

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import librosa.display
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=1000, frameon=False)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
ax.axis('off')
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, cmap='gray', x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')
plt.savefig("test.jpg", bbox_inches=0, pad_inches=0)
```

But I have been completely unable to figure out how to reimport the jpg in such a way as to recreate the audio from it. I realise is not as simple as just importing the jpg in the same way as the tiff and in saving it as a lossy format like jpg is going to result in some significant loss of quality, but I would be ok with that if the resulting audio at least slightly resembled what went in.I have looked into code to do similar things but their approach has been much more complicated such as using the colour channels to encode phase etc, I have been happy with the quality of the griffinlim reconstruction so am happy to skip that. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You are happy with the quality you get when using 32-bit TIFF as the input?

Comment: Yeah, it has some slight artifacts but it generally sounds pretty good. I am only working with dialog samples so there aren't any higher frequencies that might show up the short comings more. Its for an art project and I don't mind if the results have a slightly 'artificial' character.

Answer (score 0):

As you have alluded to, finding the waveform from a magnitude spectrogram with Griffin-Lim will have some limitations in fidelity. But if you are happy with the results in that case, then the issue is specific to the JPEG encoding (or decoding).

First, your way of saving the JPEG is wrong. You should not plot the values. But instead save the spectrogram array of values, using PIL. The same way you do for TIFF.

There are two key challenges when encoding a magnitude spectrogram into a JPEG:

1. Limited precision. Only 8-bit integers are supported in JPEG
2. Compression artifacts. JPEG uses lossy compression designed for vision
3. Color downsampling. JPEG uses spatial downsampling of Cr/Cb

Regarding 2) - turn off all compression in the start. You can try to re-introduce it later, but get the simple case working first.

Regarding 1. You must make sure your spectrogram values fit into the range 0-255. A good starting point is to decibel-scale the spectrogram (using for example `librosa.power_to_db()`), and then use a linear mapping between the values you get and 0-255. The key to decoding the spectrogram later is to know these values, so you can reverse the process. This can either be done by having fixed/hard-coding scaling values, but it might be tricky to find values that work for all audio/spectrogram input. Or you can store the scaling factors as metadata in JPEG, using a custom EXIF tag.

Regarding 3) Make sure that you are not saving color JPEGs. Instead, use a single greyscale/luminosity channel.

PNG would be a bit less limiting, if you do not get appropriate quality from JPEG. As it supports 16-bit values, and uses lossless compression.

I have stored magnitude spectrograms successfully in JPEG files. However, we never did convert it back to audio. Instead, it was used as spectrogram values for machine learning and computing acoustical parameters such as short-time sound levels.

Comment: Yeah, the bit I am really stuck on is converting the imported jpg or png to an array to feed back in to librosa. With the tiff I was able to just load it and convert it straight into an array to convert it but with the jpg there needs to be some resizing etc first which I can't get my head around. I am not too worried about some or even a significant amount of quality loss I just need the resulting output to at least resemble what went in.

Comment: by using im =Image.fromarray(Xdb).convert('L') I am able to save a jpg or png that I can reopen and convert. The result is really noisy but its a start. I suspect the data can be scaled better before saving the image as the contrast is extremely low which I assume means its not using as much af the available bit depth.

Comment: Good to hear there is some progress. For getting the scaling right, I recommend plotting the histogram of values of the spectrogram, before and after the scaling operation. A resonable strategy is to pick scaling values such that 1%,99% percentile maps to 0,255

Comment: Make sure to save as grayscale also! I added some lines about that in the answer